# Adding classes to item.GetPropertyValue() auto-generated p elements (Umbraco)

Tags: c#, html, razor, properties, umbraco

It seems whenever I call the GetPropertyValue() function, a p elements is automatically generated, meaning I can't wrap my call in my own implemented p element. I need to add a few classes to this element, but I am unable to, as the auto generated element is only created at runtime.

This is my call:

```
@(item.GetPropertyValue("desscription"))
```

When i wrap this in a p element with a class like this:

```
<p class="static-heigth">@(item.GetPropertyValue("desscription"))</p>
```

The browser adds an empty p element, as well as a p element containing a span with my property string.

How do I add classes and data-types to p elements containing my property values?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's "the browser" that adds the elements and not, say, a Rich Text Editor in Umbraco?

If you debug your way through, you'll be able to see exactly what's coming from Umbraco and what's not. Or, if the property is in fact getting its value from a Rich Text Editor which has a "HTML" or "<>" button in the backoffice, you can easily check what HTML the RTE generates.

Comment: There is no RTE on the site I am working on, so I don't think that is the case.

Comment: Fair enough. Have you tried debugging to see what the actual value of the property is? If you can't debug, try putting a <pre> or <code> tag around your property value and see what it contains. What is the datatype of the property?